# jQuery .hover doesn't loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a codepen here: http://codepen.io/huwrowlands/pen/GgmjqX

HTML:

```
<div class="site-branding">
  <a href="#">
    <img alt="Land" class="site-logo site-logo-land" src="http://website-test-lab.com/sites/landchain/wp-content/themes/landchain/assets/img/land.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Basic Styles */
.site-logo {        
    visibility: hidden;
    max-width: 127px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}



/* Animation CSS */
.slideRight{
    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight; 

    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateX(-2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }
    50%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(8%);
    }
    65%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(4%);
    }
    95%{
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2%);
    }           
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
/**/
.slideRightLeft{
    animation-name: slideRightLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRightLeft; 

    animation-duration: 1s ;    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideRightLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }       
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%);
  }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRightLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%);
  }     
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
//Animations (Delay)
        jQuery(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery('.site-logo-land').addClass("slideRight");
            }, 1000);
        });


jQuery( ".site-logo" ).hover(function() {
  jQuery( this ).addClass( "slideRightLeft" );
});
```

On page load, the Land logo animates in by adding a class which is controlled by CSS keyframe animations.
I also have a jQuery snippet to add another class to animate he Land logo on hover.

What I require, is that the hover effect to work each time a user hovers over the Land logo. Currently, it only does this once.

Not sure, if this is something to do with my CSS keyframes animation code, or something I need to fix with my jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing an answer since I cannot comment cause of my low rep (I need at least 50 to do so). But taking the suggestions from Mario A I resolved the issue of the jump on `mouseout`.

First of all I made some work on your css. I added a `transition: 1s transform` to the `site-logo` class, then I removed the keyframe animation for the `.slideRightLeft` class and added a simple `transform: translate(-50%)` since with I wasn't able to make the transition work with the keyframe animation. With these changes the text was sliding to the right on hover and if you took off your mouse at any point it would slide back into the original position, but if you left your mouse over the image it would remain at the -50% position until you took your mouse off. Here are the relevant CSS classes:

```
.site-logo {        
    max-width: 127px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  transition: 1s transform;
  -webkit-transition: 1s -webkit-transform;
}
.slideRightLeft{
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

To resolve that I added a new setTimeout of 1s to your JS and have it remove the `slideRightLeft`class, this way if you leave your mouse over the image it would return to the original position within 1s. Also having seen what Mario A had done with the JS I thought it would be simpler to have it all on the `.hover` function, hence I change the `addClass` to `toggleClass` and added the `removeClass` for the `slideRight` class on the hover function. Here's the updated JS:

```
//Animations (Delay)
        jQuery(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery('.site-logo-land').addClass("slideRight");
            }, 1000);
        });

jQuery( ".site-logo" ).hover(function() {
  var curObj = this;
  jQuery( this ).toggleClass( "slideRightLeft" );
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery( curObj ).removeClass( "slideRightLeft" );
  }, 1000);
  jQuery( this ).removeClass( "slideRight" );
});
```

You can check it out here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwmJRN

Hope I could help!

### EDIT

After publishing this I found a bug on the code where if you leave the mouse until the animation finishes and then move it out the animation fires up again, to resolve this I added the following to the JS:

```
jQuery( ".site-logo" ).on('mouseout', function(){
  jQuery( this ).removeClass( "slideRightLeft" );
});
```

This solves that issue and everything else working as before.

Comment: I just noticed a bug on my code when you let the animation finish and move the mouse out the animation fires again, the way to solve it is by adding another jQuery function as follows: `jQuery( ".site-logo" ).on('mouseout', function(){
  jQuery( this ).removeClass( "slideRightLeft" );
});` I've added it to the code pen above.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `hover` function doesn't work like the css `:hover` class where styles are just applied on hover, and removed after mouseout. You need to remove the class on mouseout again:

```
jQuery( ".site-logo" ).on('mouseout', function() {
  jQuery( this ).removeClass( "slideRightLeft" );
});
```

Comment: This causes a 'jump' if I move my mouse away during animation. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: this is because auf the class slideRight , I made some adjustments here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPmRGL

Comment: Still jumps I'm afraid?

Comment: My fault, I hadn't saved  it.

Comment: Looking good. Thank you. One more thing: if I were to hover my pointer over and then quickly move it from the logo; the logo snaps back instead of continuing with the animation. Is there a way to make sure it completes the animation? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I fear that is not that simple, because as far as I know javascript isn't able to find out when a css transition is finished. You would need to take a different approach, e.g. do the entire animation in js

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following to the `.slideRightLeft` class:

```
-webkit-animation: slideRightLeft 1.3s infinite;
animation: slideRightLeft 1.3s infinite;
```

Check this [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPVGaO) for a working demo.

---

## Edit

You can find the implementation using jQuery's `animate()` function [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEmyQN). Note the added `style` to the `img`.

**JS**

```
jQuery( ".site-logo" ).hover(function() {
  jQuery( this ).animate({
    left: "-=50"
  }, 1000)
  .animate({
    left: "+=50"
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Almost there! Maybe it's the way I have worded my question above but I can see in your demo that once the logo has been hovered over, it keeps moving. I guess that what the 'infinite' in the css does? Is there a way to have this move, only on hover. So it animates once on hover, then if hovered over again, it animates again. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I understand now, please check the approach above using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css:hover selector. You can do something like this:

```
.site-logo:hover
{
  animation-name: slideRightLeft;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideRightLeft; 
  animation-duration: 1s ;    
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```